# Developer API with free account

Tags: api, smtp, gmail

I don't think I'm in a unique situation. But haven't been able to find any solutions.

I want to use a Developer API for a Gmail SMTP plugin, and it's for a client that has a free account. We manage their website, and the plugin requires a developer API to improve delivery performance to their e-mail-adress.

However, when I try to create one I get the following message:

> You are using a G Suite account that does not have access to the Developers Console. Ask your administrator to enable the 'Google Developers Console' option in G Suite Admin console.

When I try to find the administrator, Google states there is no administrator for this account. It looks like it's a professional business e-mail, because it doesn't end with `@gmail.com` but with the clients brand-name.

We do have a developer account but with an API from that account login error's pop up, which makes sense because the API has to be connected to the email adress for as far as I understand the documentation.

What am I missing here? The steps I need to take to activate Google Developers Console on my account cannot be found. Only thing I can find are info pages about the developers console. Been looking for quite some time now, if anyone can help that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The customer must have applied for a gsuite account.   You need to find the admin of that account.   They are the only person who is going to be able to help you.    I have never heard of a free Gsuite account though.

Comment: Hi DalmTo, thank you for your reply. However, when visiting admin.google.com I get the following notice: "admin.google.com is only for G Suite-accounts. You cannot login at admin.google.com with a regular Gmail-account." We haven't been able to find any administrator account connected, and been trying to solve this puzzle for a few days now.

Comment: Sounds to me like the email address in question is a normal Gmail account nad not part of a Gsuite account.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a @gmail.com account then? 
Is it possible for them to have made a brand name adress in a free account of gmail?

Comment: Nope you can turn any email account into a Google account I have with my domain email account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer support issue

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the email address you are using is a attached to a normal Google account.

Any email can be used to create a Google account it doesn't need to be part of the Gmail.com domain.

unfortunately you can only use gsuite with service accounts and the Gmail api.

Assuming that you have the password for this account you can use SMTP to access the Google mail for this user.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp

Comment: So it seems, thank you for answering my question.
I got confused because of the message I stated in my question. That message/notice from Google was incorrect, now my situation is clear. Thanks!